# Connect access query to excel with dynamic input parameter

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I've got some queries I have connected to an excel sheet that I refresh in order to get the latest data.

Is it possible to make excel "ask" for input parameters for one column lets say?

I am looking to get data by company so wondering if it's possible to do it as in access (type [company]:) in the field criteria

If I save the query like that in access it won't let me connect it to excel

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "ASK"?  Do you want user input?  If so, then try the inputbox in VBA.

Comment: No, not the way you have done it. For that, you need to write the SQL queries in Excel and connect Access to Excel using a connection string and then you can build your queries using any variable that will be entered by the user when asked

Comment: @ -lbo. I've got the queries ready set in access-is it possible to copy the SQL from there into WWC's code below? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alright another edit.

Here it is, I created a database, its simple.
The database is called "Database1.accdb"

[image]

There are more records than shown in the screen shot.

I created a workbook with one sheet, its name is "AccessDBtest.xlsm"

I created a button on Sheet1 and entered the field parameter I wanted in the cell beside it, C3 or (3,3) in (row,col) format.

This is the code that works returning the data set (without field names) based on the input criteria.  I made a msgBox before the SQL query execution so that I could look at it first.  You don't need that if you do not want it, good for testing.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
Dim fieldSTR As String
Dim placementRange As Range

Dim rs As Object 'record set

Dim conn As Object
Dim strQuery As String

Dim myDB As String

Set inputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set placementRange = inputSheet.Range("E2")

fieldSTR = CStr(inputSheet.Cells(3, 3).Value) 'C3 cell

myDB = "C:\Users\Documents\0_Excel Projects\Testing\Database1.accdb"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    With conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"    'For *.ACCDB Databases
        .ConnectionString = myDB
        .Open
    End With


strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " & _
            "tbl_test WHERE tbl_test.Color = " & "'" & fieldSTR & "'" & ";"

'The below gives the same result as * but you could limit the fields returned as well
'tbl_test.ID, tbl_test.Color, tbl_test.number

'just using Color also works you do not need to reference the table directly

MsgBox (strQuery)

Set rs = conn.Execute(strQuery)

placementRange.CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

See if you can map what you want to do using that.
I wanted to capture a string from a cell and then use that string in the query.

Here is the MsgBox before the query executes (what access will see):
I tested it with * for all fields and below you can see that I called up specific fields, they both work.

[image]

And here is what happens after I clear the msgBox, the recordset is pulled and pasted starting in the range I specified Range.("E3") on the sheet I specified (Sheet1)[image]

As you can see, we can pull queries from a database using input that is found on a current sheet.

Let me know if this helps your situation.

We can dig deeper if required.

-WWC

Comment: Thanks @- WWC. I don't quite understand the fieldSTR bit. Will that be my input parameter? Also will copying the SQL from the query do?

Comment: Yes the fieldSTR is the field name captured from part1.  Do you want to type it in, select it in a list, read the field names from a table and then make a list?  Basically you seemed to convey the field desired might change.  In your example fieldSTR would be "Company".  Copy the SQL query might do with a few tweaks, the query is assigned to sqlSTR so it can be easily called.  This should serve as a "beginning" depending on how you intend to tell excel what field and what table you are after (if more than one of each). - WWC

Comment: @-WWC. The field will remain the same each time (will be Company) and I would like to type in the company name I wish to run the query for. So basically each time call the query excel will "ask" me to type in the company name I want to extract data for.

Comment: @-WWC.I've managed to get some queries working but some others do not. I am not entirely sure of the syntax since I am fairly knew to VBA. Will you be ok to check my SQL statement for me and tell me how to sort out the syntax ?Thanks

Comment: Ok, have you figured out how to get the parameter from a selected input box?  My only fear here is the user needs to already know what the field names are, if you are the only user then its probably ok - WWC

Comment: This is a good place for query building, Access uses a SQL style format but not completely. http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut14.htm - WWC

Comment: No I haven't really managed to get the "Company" to be populated in the query through an input box. My query (the working one) looks like this when picking company name: WHERE (((COMPANY_1.COMPANY_NAME)= 'Total'). I've tried replacing 'Total' with 'fieldSTR' while having set that field.STR=InputBox but doesn't really work.

Comment: COMPANY_1 is the table name? - WWC

Comment: @-WWC. Yes exactly

Comment: @-WWC.I thought of a simpler solution since I will be working on different excel sheets each time. I am pulling in all the data from tables where the COMPANY_NAME is in a specific cell within the workbook. How do I reference that cell in the SQL command? I've tried ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("X10").Value but the code won't work.Thanks

Comment: @Mourst This is achievable.  I modify the answer a little to show grabbing a specific cell and converting it to a string.  But the way you describe it, if you open a workbook and are on a worksheet, if you know what column your Companies will be listed in (are they read from the Database?) then we can write a selectionChange script that when you select a company a function runs that will run the query for that target cell (Company name).

Comment: That is how it sounds like I would approach it, without knowing the entire project, I would probably read in the company names from the table, into a certain place on the worksheet (and define that range).  Then if a user selects a company then the query runs for that company and place the data somewhere (a sheet, a different workbook?). - WWC

Comment: @-WWC.Will this approach work when I am actually querying a table?To simplify things I made my queries in access to create tables and then Ill query the table without having to type in the query in VBA. I've tried the bit of code you've added with the datacell but the thing is still not working.My sqlSTR looks like this :sqlSTR = "SELECT * FROM [CORPORATE-Cash flow_NEW]" _ ##table name
& "WHERE Company = datacell"

Comment: I have updated the answer on a quick "test build" that I made this afternoon.  Apologies I am usually lazy and grab the whole data table copy it to a worksheet and then dive into excel pivots and etc in vba, basically I filter once in Excel, but I am not dealing with very big databases at this point.  But being selective is probably more efficient in many situations. Cheers,

Comment: Thanks WWC. It works perfect now!Just wondering-is it possible to add an OR statement when querying the table? So I am looking to get "tbl_test WHERE tbl_test.Color = " & "'" & fieldSTR & "'" & ";" OR tbl_test.Number = "something else". thanks!

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but yes logic is allowed in the queries OR and AND as the major ones.